# How to run AVD emulator from .bat without a console window?

Tags: android-studio, batch-file, cmd, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to create a shortcut to run AVD emulator without opening Android Studio. So I use a `.bat` file which contains next line:

```
emulator @Pixel_2_API_29
```

When running it I, of course, get a console window, which I really don't need:

[image: cmd]

If I close it, emulator also closes. Is there any way to run it in background or something similar just to get a running emulator without any console windows (the same behaviour can be achieved if you run emulator from Android Studio and close it immideately)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

[image]

---

This is a hybrid cmd/js/vbs/batch and this code can do this job for you, just save as .cmd and enjoy!

---

```ps1
<!-- :
@echo off && mode 050,03 && title <nul && title .\%~nx0 && for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('
%__APPDIR__%wScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf" @Pixel_2_API_29 ^& cls ') do exit /b 2>nul >nul
--> <job> <script language = "vbscript"> Set WshShell =CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run chr(34)&"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe"&_
Chr(34)&WScript.Arguments(0)&Chr(34), 0, False: Set WshShell = Nothing </script></job>
```

---

> - **Obs.:**
>
> You can read more about hybrid bat **[`in this link`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5543)**, and see some **[`sample code/files here.`](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433)**
>
> ---

- For using with arguments, just add quote in for loop bat session:

```ps1
"arg1 arg2 ag3" <==> " -memory 4096" obs.: 3rd line in code!
```

```ps1
<!-- :
@echo off && mode 050,03 && title <nul && title .\%~nx0 && for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('
%__APPDIR__%wScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf" @Pixel_2_API_29 " -memory 4096"^>nul')do exit/b
--> <job> <script language = "vbscript"> Set WshShell =CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run chr(34)&"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe"&_
Chr(34)&WScript.Arguments(0)&Chr(34)&Chr(34)&WScript.Arguments(1)&Chr(34), 0, False:
Set WshShell=Nothing</script></job>
```

---

Comment: That's [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) and default Pixel 2 emulator with enabled Google Play.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks like magic but works like a charm, got a challenge to dig into this stuff, can be helpful sometimes, I assume. The strange thing is that I didn't noticed significant differences in opening time or perfomance when Android Studio is closed or opened, need to perform some time testes...

Comment: And how can I pass another two command line arguments in this solution, for example if I want to run `emulator @Pixel_2_API_29 -memory 4096`?

Comment: Thanks in advance, just add it to your answer.

Comment: Oh, that works, thanks a lot, now use new convenient way to launch all my AVD. Btw, that's android 10 phone Pixel 2 with enabled Google Play

Answer (score 0):

Look into running the [batch as a service](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunBatchFileAsAService.html)

If you can live with the console window:

Create a shortcut to the batch file. Right click on the shortcut - Properties - Run: Minimized

[image: screenshot change shortcut properties]

[image: screenshot change shortcut properties run minimized]

Comment: That's a bit better, but still opens a console window that pollutes alt+tab section and if accidently close will shut down an emulator.

Comment: You can't use `start` as Target for shortcut. And the `cmd /c` solution also results in getting cmd window :/

Comment: Tried creating a service using `sc create "AVD emulator" start=demand displayname= "AVD emulator" binpath="C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Run emulator.bat"`, but unfortunately it couldn't start, receive `Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`